# Merging dataframes by ranges of datetimes in R

Tags: r, datetime, join, merge, lubridate

I have two dataframes. The first dataframe `Observations` shows the date/times that a surveyor recorded events of interest, and a unique `ID` number for each type of event:

```r
library(lubridate)
Observations <- data.frame(Time = dmy_hms(paste(c("13-7-2022 10:01:01","13-7-2022 14:02:01","15-7-2022 10:01:01", "15-7-2022 16:01:01"))), ID = c(1,3,1))
```

The second dataframe `Sites` shows what date/time the surveyor started and stopped looking for events (i.e., this describes the possible times that events could have been observed).  `TimeStart` is the time the surveyor began looking for an event, `TimeEnd` is when they stopped. `Sites` also contains the latitude and longitude where the surveyor was looking for events between `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd`.

```r
Sites <- data.frame(TimeStart = dmy_hms(paste(c("13-7-2022 10:00:00","13-7-2022 14:00:00","15-7-2022 10:00:00", "15-7-2022 16:00:00"))),
                    TimeEnd = dmy_hms(paste(c("13-7-2022 10:05:00","13-7-2022 14:05:00","15-7-2022 10:05:00", "15-7-2022 16:05:00"))),
                    Latitude = c("11.1111", "11.2222", "11.1234", "11.1487"),
                    Longitude = c("99.1257", "99.3478", "99.6241", "99.6214"))
```

So the `Time` that events are recorded by the surveyor (i.e., recorded in `Observations`) falls within one of the time ranges shown in `Sites$TimeStart` and `Sites$TimeEnd`.

I would like to merge these two dataframes so that rows for each event (`ID`) recorded in `Observations` contains the `Latitude` and `Longitude` where the surveyor was searching during the corresponding `Time`, as well as when they started `TimeStart` and stopped `TimeEnd` searching for each period.

In the end, `Observations` would look like this:

```r
Time                ID  Latitude Longitude  TimeStart              TimeEnd    
2022-07-13 10:01:01 1   11.1111   99.1257   2022-07-13 10:00:00   2022-07-13 10:05:00
2022-07-13 14:02:01 3   11.2222   99.3478   2022-07-13 14:00:00   2022-07-13 14:05:00
2022-07-15 10:01:01 2   11.1234   99.6241   2022-07-15 10:00:00   2022-07-15 10:05:00
2022-07-15 16:01:01 1   11.1487   99.6214   2022-07-15 16:00:00   2022-07-15 16:05:00
```

How can we merge this data by times when `Observations$Time` falls within a "range of times" shown in `Sites$TimeStart` and `Sites$TimeEnd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by retrieving the index (row number) in `Sites` that fulfills the time condition:

```
Observations$siteindex <- sapply(Observations$Time, function(x) which(x<=Sites$TimeEnd&x>=Sites$TimeStart)[1]) # first matching row into Sites
Sites$siteindex <- 1:nrow(Sites)
result <- merge(Observations, Sites, by="siteindex")
  siteindex                Time ID           TimeStart             TimeEnd Latitude Longitude
1         1 2022-07-13 10:01:01  1 2022-07-13 10:00:00 2022-07-13 10:05:00  11.1111   99.1257
2         2 2022-07-13 14:02:01  3 2022-07-13 14:00:00 2022-07-13 14:05:00  11.2222   99.3478
3         3 2022-07-15 10:01:01  1 2022-07-15 10:00:00 2022-07-15 10:05:00  11.1234   99.6241
4         4 2022-07-15 16:01:01  2 2022-07-15 16:00:00 2022-07-15 16:05:00  11.1487   99.6214
```

The data might be a bit different because your `data.frame` is incorrect: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3`